After installing python3.11 none of the general python/python3 executables are symlinked to them
I have installed python 3.11 via Homebrew.  There are many posts about similar issues with python@3.X not updating python/python3, etc.  But I have not seen a solution that fixes the fact that the executables including pip/pip3, pydoc, idle, wheel are all not available.
cd /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9/bin
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9/bin$ ll
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 steve admin  66 Apr  2 01:25 python3.11-config -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 steve admin  59 Apr  2 01:25 python3.11 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11
lrwxr-xr-x  1 steve admin  58 Apr  2 01:25 pydoc3.11 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/pydoc3.11
lrwxr-xr-x  1 steve admin  57 Apr  2 01:25 idle3.11 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/idle3.11
lrwxr-xr-x  1 steve admin  58 Apr  2 01:25 2to3-3.11 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/2to3-3.11
-rwxr-xr-x  1 steve wheel 233 Jul  6 22:27 wheel3.11
-rwxr-xr-x  1 steve wheel 246 Jul  6 22:27 pip3.11
drwxr-xr-x  9 steve admin 288 Jul  6 22:27 .

It's not simply adding the new directory to the path:  it would require symlinking each and every one.   What is the way to do this?
Update. I needed to make some forward progress so have manually symlinked python[/3] and pip[/3].  I am still looking for a more general process to do this: it is doubtful  that everyone is creating 14 symlinks manually each time  a new version of python is installed.   [I will wait through downvotes to see if someone else has noticed a better way.]

According to your directory listing those components appear to be installed.

@OldBoy there is no python or python3 [and similarly to the other executables].

The directory listing shows what names they have been installed as.

@OldBoy.  We seem to be discussing at cross purposes.  python[/3],  and  pip[/3] are not symlinked to these python3.11 / pip3.11 installed executables.  I have updated the title of this post since you and apparently others did not follow this.

I understand what you are complainng about, but the only information you have given us is the above listing, which gives no clue as to how you installed this version in the first place.

@OldBoy. OK it's fair to ask about "how was this installed": and the question has been updated with that info.  But your comments do not address the missing symlinks - rather "well the 3.X versions are there".

OK, well it would seem that the issue is with Homebrew, but I am afraid it is not a product that I have any experience of.

Maybe the question at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450303/how-to-make-python-3-11-my-default-python3-with-brew will help.

@OldBoy. Those lead to the same spaghetti of requiring 14 symlinks to be re-created each time.

brew unlink && brew link
OLDVERSION=3.12
NEWVERSION=3.11
brew unlink python@$OLDVERSION && brew link python@$NEWVERSION
python -V

Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4... 25 symlinks removed.
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9... 15 symlinks created.
Python 3.11.9

ls -lrta /usr/local/bin

lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    37 Jul  7 10:33  2to3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/2to3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    42 Jul  7 10:33  2to3-3.12 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/2to3-3.12
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    38 Jul  7 10:33  idle3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/idle3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    41 Jul  7 10:33  idle3.12 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/idle3.12
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    37 Jul  7 10:33  pip3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/pip3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    40 Jul  7 10:33  pip3.12 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/pip3.12
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    39 Jul  7 10:33  pydoc3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/pydoc3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    42 Jul  7 10:33  pydoc3.12 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/pydoc3.12
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    40 Jul  7 10:33  python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    47 Jul  7 10:33  python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    43 Jul  7 10:33  python3.12 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/python3.12
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    50 Jul  7 10:33  python3.12-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/python3.12-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    39 Jul  7 10:33  wheel3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/wheel3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 steve admin    42 Jul  7 10:33  wheel3.12 -> ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/bin/wheel3.12

